# PHP Order by variable after str_pad

Tags: php, string, date

I want to sort my table by variable that i made from sql data itself. So here the code

```
$sql="select * from schedule";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$new_date=str_pad($data['date'], 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

is that possible if `$sql="select * from schedule order by $new_date"` ?

i've tried that code but it didn't worked. So i will really appreciate if you answer my question, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can't you just use a where clause? `$sql="select * from schedule where date='$new_date'"`

Answer (score 0):

"select * from schedule order by variable"
Note variable is a column in schedule

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't show what you're trying to accomplish. Sorting your table should occur in the query `$sql`, so for example... `SELECT * FROM schedule ORDER BY colName` would be a way to sort on colName.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LPAD(str, len, padstr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to pad directly in your query:

```
ORDER BY LPAD(column, 10, 0)
```